# Getting decimal separator error while exporting an Access table to CSV

Tags: sql, vb.net, csv, ms-access-2010

I am trying to export an Access table as an Excel CSV file in the following way:

```vb
Dim workSpace As Access.Dao.Workspace = CommonAccessMethods.SetWorkspace(PATH_WG, "Admin", "")
Dim dbCSF As Access.Dao.Database = workSpace.OpenDatabase(PATH_CS)
Dim strQuery As String
strQuery = "SELECT * INTO [Text;HDR=NO;DATABASE=" & FOLDER_ECD & "\A].[tblAEC.csv] FROM [tblAEC];"
dbCSF.Execute(strQuery)
```

I get the following error while running it:

> **System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException**: 'Text file specification
> field separator matches decimal separator or text

The source table does not contain any punctuation.
It contains 3 fields.

Example source table:

| ID | CODE | BOOL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1452 | ABC | FALSE |
| 2458 | 14LP | TRUE |

What I am looking for is a way to export an Access table into a new CSV file.

Comment: You might need to create a "schema.ini" file to be able to specify the delimiter, as shown in [Exporting MSAccess Tables as Unicode with Tilde delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160532/exporting-msaccess-tables-as-unicode-with-tilde-delimiter). Perhaps the "text file specification field separator" has been set to an unfortuante value somewhere else, such as in Windows regional settings.

Comment: What is this supposed to evaluate to: `FOLDER_ECD & "\A].[tblAEC.csv]`?

Comment: Have you decided not to use the MS-Access built-in `TransferText` function?